# Electron process running after closing, eating RAM and Processor

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, chromium, electron-builder

I'm working on a new Electron application and frequently have to go into my task manager and kill a bunch of lingering Electron processes as it eats away at my ram. In the screenshot, one of them is using 17,000 MB of RAM, slowing my laptop down. Is there a way to prevent the processes from running after quitting the application? Will this 'feature' be present when running a build and deploying to production?

Is there a way to monitor exactly why this process is eating up so much RAM? With the application closed, I don't have any access to the dev console

[Lingering electron process using a lot of RAM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TT5Nm.png)

Answer (score 0):

Does your code call app.quit when you close it? No idea why you are getting that much ram usage, but if you don't have these lines it would make sense that the executable continues to run.

```
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        console.log("Closing program.")
        app.quit()
    }
})
```

Comment: Hey, yeah I'm using Electron Builder, and all the app.quits have been put in background.js for the various OS's (although this will only be released on Windows). I think I'll just have to monitor various peoples task managers when releasing to staging to see if this is going to be an issue or just a weird 'feature' that crops up in development